# Does anyone recognize this door part?

Tags: doors

We put up two old french doors, and at the top they each have a spring loaded metal ball that supposedly keeps the doors shut.  I believe they are supposed to slide up against something when they are closed.  But I'm not sure what to get for the doorway, whether something exists, or if I have to make something myself.  I'll include this picture, sorry for the poor quality.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a [Striker plate](http://www.doorware.com/site/product.cfm?id=162022) much like the ones on a standard doorway. [image: Like this one]

Answer (score 2):

That spring loaded steel ball is known as a *ball catch* or sometimes as a *bullet catch*. If you search for either of those, you'll also find the matching strike plates that you need.